# How to take a class, that uses a parameter pack and typename, as an input parameter for a function(c++)

Tags: c++, class, templates

I created a class that takes a `typename` template variable and a `parameter pack`. In the next step i want to be able to pass two objects of that class to my function.

My main problem is, passing the template parameters and the objects correctly to be able to use my function.
My class implementation.

```
//auto as template parameter is for non-type parameter(c++17)
template <auto value> constexpr auto DIM = value;
//constexpr on values in header files(c++17)
inline constexpr auto const DIM3 = DIM <3>;
inline constexpr auto const DIM2 = DIM <2>;


enum Index : int {lower = 0, upper = 1};


template<int base, int exponent>
int constexpr pow(){
    if constexpr(exponent == 0){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return base * pow<base, exponent-1>();
    }
}
template<int Size, typename T>
struct Array{
    T array[Size];
    Array(const T * a){
        for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++){
            array[i] = a[i];
        }
    }
};



//auto as template parameter is for non-type parameters(c++17)
template<typename T = double, auto ...IndicesN>
class MatrixND{

private:
    const Array<pow<DIM3, sizeof...(IndicesN)>(), T> matrix;

public:
    MatrixND(const T * arr): matrix(arr){}

    template<auto ...args>
    auto constexpr getElement(){
    }
};
```

The function that takes MatrixND objects:

```
template<auto posT1, auto posT2, typename A, typename B>
auto constexpr function(const MatrixND<A> tensor1, const MatrixND<B> tensor2){

    return 0;
}
```

I tried the following, but it throws an error message "no matching function call":

```
const double arrayc[27] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27};
auto matrix1 = new MatrixND<double, upper, lower, lower>(arrayc);

function<1,1, decltype(matrix1), decltype(matrix1)>(matrix1, matrix1);
```

The error message:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘function<1, 1, MatrixND<double, (Index)1, (Index)0, (Index)0>*, MatrixND<double, (Index)1, (Index)0, (Index)0>*>(MatrixND<double, (Index)1, (Index)0, (Index)0>*&, MatrixND<double, (Index)1, (Index)0, (Index)0>*&)’
     contraction<1,1, decltype(matrix1), decltype(matrix1)>(matrix1, matrix1);
```

Comment: `auto constexpr function(const A & tensor1, B const & tensor2){`?

Comment: sidenote: `pow` is not declared `constexpr` (and it takes arguments) so `const Array<pow<DIM3, sizeof...(IndicesN)>(), T> matrix;` won't compile. I presume you defined your own?

Comment: @AndyG i am sorry, i forgot the code. I edited my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the function as

```
function<1,1, decltype(matrix1), decltype(matrix1)>(matrix1, matrix1);
```

you say that the template arguments `A` and `B` are `decltype(matrix1)`, meaning they are really `MatrixND<double, upper, lower, lower>`.

That in turn means that e.g. the argument `tensor1` will have the type `const MatrixND<MatrixND<double, upper, lower, lower>>`. Which is not what you pass.

A possible solution would be to not use `MatrixND<A>` (and `MatrixND<B>`) in the argument list, but only

```
template<auto posT1, auto posT2, typename A, typename B>
auto constexpr function(const A tensor1, const B tensor2){

    return 0;
}
```

And you should probably pass references instead of values as arguments as well.

---

If you do like above with the function you also don't need the template arguments for the types of `A` and `B` as that would be deduced by the compiler:

```
function<1,1>(matrix1, matrix1);
```

Comment: would it be worth to add, that a type trait and static assert could be used to make sure that `A` and `B` are indeed `MatrixND`?

Comment: when i use `const A tensor1`  and `const B tensor2` i am not able to use the functions of my class. E.g tensor1.getElement<...>().  Is there any way to use my objects function?

Comment: @M.Mac Why? What problems does that give you?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i am sorry, it works, but my autocompletion doesnt.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the parameter packs to the template parameters of `function`.  Using

```
template<auto posT1, auto posT2, typename A, typename B, auto ...AIndicesN, auto ...BIndicesN>
auto constexpr function(const MatrixND<A, AIndicesN...> tensor1, const MatrixND<B, BIndicesN...> tensor2){

    return 0;
}
```

Allows you to call function like

```
auto foo = function<1,1>(matrix1, matrix1);
```

---

Do note that for this to compile with your code you need to change

```
auto matrix1 = new MatrixND<double, upper, lower, lower>(arrayc);
```

to

```
auto matrix1 = MatrixND<double, upper, lower, lower>(arrayc);
```

since you don't actually want a pointer to a `MatrixND` but an actual `MatrixND` object.